# is there any simpler way to refresh a page in rails

Tags: ruby

Guys i have tried to refresh my page with a button..
`<input type="reset" value="Refresh" />`
but it not refreshing, not to refresh the textboxes jst to refresh the entire page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Reload Page" onClick="history.go(0)">
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is four years old, but I wanted to put out the snippet I used using Rails formatting.

```
<%= button_to "Refresh", "", { :onclick => "history.go(0)" } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case this works very well:

```
= link_to "close", "", :onclick => '$("#ajax_form").hide(); history.go(0); return false;', :style => "color:white"
```